# Removing views from superview in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a cell class 'NewsCell' (subclass of UITableViewCell) that I use for two different kinds of news: OrganizationNews and ProjectNews. These news has common things, but some of elements are different. Namely, when my cell is used for ProjectNews I want to hide Organization's logo, when it is for OrganizationNews I want to hide Project's name button.

I have 'configureCell(_, forNews, ofProject)' method. I call it in 'NewsViewController'. I used 'removeFromSuperview' method, because I need to rearrange my elements in 'NewsCell'. Changing 'isHidden' value won't give me that effect.

So, that is the issue. I have 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' exception in the lines projectNameButton.removeFromSuperview() or logoImageView.removeFromSuperview().
What should I do?

```
// NewsViewController.swift
func configureCell(_ cell: NewsCell, forNews news: News, ofProject project: Project? = nil) {
    //...
    if news is OrganizationNews {
        cell.projectNameButton.removeFromSuperview()
    } else if news is ProjectNews {
        cell.logoImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    // ...
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let news = newsCollection[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.newsCell, for: indexPath) as! NewsCell
    configureCell(cell, forNews: news)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: It's just outlets from storyboard. 
   IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView! and
   IBOutlet weak var projectNameButton: UIButton!

Comment: Either use two different cell classes or put the logic to show the proper subviews in the cell class, not in the view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy I have the same issue when this 'configure' method is in the cell class.

Comment: Your outlets aren't connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the removing lines as below,

```
if news is OrganizationNews {
    cell.projectNameButton?.removeFromSuperview()
} else if news is ProjectNews {
    cell.logoImageView?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

This will fix the issue. But a good approach would be to create separate classes for each cell. You can create a base class to keep common logic there.

Comment: This avoids the crash. It does not fix the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A UITableView or UICollectionView are built on the ***reuse*** concept,  where the cells are reused and repopulated when you work on it.

When you try to call `dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`, it sometimes returns something that is created before.  So,  suppose you dequed before something which had all controls, then removed one (`removeFromSuperview`),  then tried to deque again, the new dequed one may NOT have the subview.

I think the best solution for you is making two different cells.

***Example:***

```
class BaseNewsCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Put the common views here
}

class OrganizationNewsCell: BaseNewsCell {
    // Put here things that are ONLY for OrganizationNewsCell
}

class ProjectNewsCell: BaseNewsCell {
    // Put here things that are ONLY for ProjectNewsCell
}
```

Then deque them from 2 different identifier by two different storyboard cells, xibs.

Or

```
class BaseNewsCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Put the common views here
}

class OrganizationNewsCell: BaseNewsCell {
    // This happens when this kind of cell is created for the first time
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        someNonCommon.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

class ProjectNewsCell: BaseNewsCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        someOtherNonCommon.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

***Note:*** This violates Liskov's principle (one of the SOLID principles), because you remove functionality from superclass in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove the subview from the **outside** of the cell. Let's refactor your code.

**NewsCell.swift**

```
final class NewsCell: UITableViewCell {
    enum Kind {
        case organization
        case project
    }

    var logoImageView: UIImageView?
    let nameLabel = UILabel()

    var kind: NewsCell.Kind {
        didSet {
            if kind != oldValue {
                setupLogoImageView()
                self.setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
    }

    init(kind: NewsCell.Kind, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        self.kind = kind
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// MARK: - Positioning
extension NewsCell {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Your layouting
        switch kind {
            case .organization:
                // Setup frame for organization typed NewsCell
            case .project:
                // Setup frame for project typed NewsCell
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Setup
extension NewsCell {
    private func setupLogoImageView() {
        logoImageView = kind == .organization ? UIImageView() : nil
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let news = newsCollection[indexPath.row]

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.newsCell) as? NewsCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = NewsCell(kind: .organization, reuseIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.newsCell)
    }

    cell!.kind = news is Organization ? .organization: .project

    return cell!
}
```